# How do you verify lower cutoff frequency from a voltage vs. time graph?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, frequency, passive-networks, graph

I am working on a laboratory assignment. I am asked to verify the lower cutoff frequency (F1) value that I calculated (~4950 HZ) using a graph.

The lab specifically asks:
"Reduce the input frequency to calculate f1. Use your calculated value as reference, but also explain what condition you must look for in your graph to verify that this is in fact your correct f1 value. Paste a screenshot of your graph, explain how you get f1."

[image: Here is the graph]

I am kind of at a loss for what condition I am supposed to be looking for. If this was a Imax vs. frequency graph, I would know what to look for. But I'm not so sure with voltage vs. time.

Comment: NVM, I figured it out.

Comment: Next time tells us the the lower cutoff frequency of what? Probably a filter, but is it low pass, band pass or high pass?

Comment: @Oldfart This was for an RLC circuit. My class hasn't gotten to filters yet

Comment: @DiogoAlbuquerque I used Vmax from the output waveform and resistance to calculate current. I used the Vmax from the input waveform and the resistance to calculate Imax. I multiplied Imax by ~0.707 and compared that value with the other calculated current value.